# managing checkbox in childview of Expandablelistview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my `ExpandableListview`, I am using `Imageview` and `Checkbox` that resembles the shape image and name,

When I tick the `checkbox` of particular child item , the other child item also gets ticked , after scrolling the checked state changes ,

Please help me to get this solved

Thanks in advance.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


_childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);     

int itemType = getChildType(groupPosition,childPosition);

Log.e("childPosition", "karjeevch "+childPosition);

ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
switch (itemType) {

case 0:
    viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView==null) {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();                
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_shape, null);
        viewHolder.shape_name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
        viewHolder.img_shape_icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_shape);


        imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://rosycontact.com/shashvat/images/"+_childText+".png", viewHolder.img_shape_icon);
        viewHolder.shape_name.setText(_childText);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        final CheckBox shape_name_temp=viewHolder.shape_name;
        viewHolder.shape_name.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (shape_name_temp.isChecked()==true) {
                    All_link.SHAPE=shape_name_temp.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });


        //new PerformBackgroungTask().execute();
    }
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
    //break;



case 1:

    viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView==null) {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_carat, null);
        viewHolder.carat_from = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_carat_from);
        viewHolder.carat_to = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ed_carat_to);

        viewHolder.carat_from.setText("jdsv");
        viewHolder.carat_to.setText("jdsv");

        All_link.CARAT_FROM=viewHolder.carat_from.getText().toString();
        All_link.CARAT_TO=viewHolder.carat_to.getText().toString();

    }
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;


case 2: 

    viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView==null) {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder(); 

        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_color, null);
        viewHolder.color_from = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spn_color_from);
        viewHolder.color_to = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spn_color_to);


        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(_context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SearchActivity.color_list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);               
        viewHolder.color_from.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewHolder.color_to.setAdapter(adapter);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        final Spinner color_from_temp=viewHolder.color_from;
        final Spinner color_to_temp=viewHolder.color_to;

        // Changing textcolor
        viewHolder.color_from.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    All_link.COLOR_FROM=color_from_temp.getSelectedItem().toString();
                       ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#003974"));                         
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
            });
        viewHolder.color_to.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                All_link.COLOR_TO=color_to_temp.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#003974"));                         
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });  
    }
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
```